# Calculate Task age in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, calendar

How to calculate the task age in asp.net usinf c# means the difference between the Assigned date selected for task  and the current date.

Comment: Are you trying to create your own task scheduler? Can you clarify?

Comment: Dont forget to upvote and mark answer as accpeted if you get the info you want..

Answer (score 0):

Ultimtly you want difference between two dates , which you can get as below

```
System.DateTime dtStartDate = new System.DateTime(2012, 9, 13, 12, 0, 0);
System.DateTime dtEndDate = new System.DateTime(2012, 9, 13, 0, 0, 0);
System.TimeSpan diffResult = dtEndDate.Subtract(dtStartDate);
Console.WriteLine("StartDate - EndDate = " + diffResult.TotalDays);
```

Comment: @Panay i have to select assign date from calendar control and it should get displayed at label.

Comment: @nidhi - so what you need to sore the vlaue of selected in variable than dispaly on the lable control and than make use of same variable for calculation..

Comment: I got the value using  DateTime dt1 = Calendar1.SelectedDate;
        DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Now;
        TimeSpan ts = dt2 - dt1;
        int numberOfDays = ts.Days;   
        Label3.Text = numberOfDays.ToString(); bt i ve to display the value in gridview in another aspx file where calendar is not used .please help me.